# Select all row for specific column query SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

i want to know what is the wrong in this query I want to select all rows for 1 column

```
 string command = "select money from User_Data";
 SqlCommand update_money = new SqlCommand(command, con_string.con);
 SqlDataReader money_reader;
 money_reader = update_money.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: simply put ... ??????????????

Comment: be more specific with your question. what exactly is wrong? "it doesn't work" is not a good question.

Comment: it give me an exception when I wrote 
 tempmoney1=(float)Convert.ToDouble(money_reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
 tempmoney2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(money_reader.GetValue(1).ToString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track - now once you have the data reader, you need to iterate over the rows:

```
string command = "select money from User_Data";

SqlCommand update_money = new SqlCommand(command, con_string.con);
SqlDataReader money_reader = update_money.ExecuteReader();

List<decimal> _allValues = new List<decimal>();

while(money_reader.Read())
{
    _allValues.Add(money_reader.GetDecimal(0));
}
```

This assumes your `money` column would be of type `decimal(x,y)` or `money` on SQL Server.

Comment: i do it but when I wrote 
decimal moneyValue = money_reader.GetMoney(1);
I got exception handle ( out of index ) although the table has 2 rows !!!!

Comment: @salamonti Because the GetMoney(ordinal) function where ordinal is the column index, not the row index.  Ordinal corresponds to the index of the field in your select statement, the the index of the row in your result set.

Comment: @salamonti: sorry, my bad - the method is called `.GetDecimal()` - not GetMoney as I falsely used.... and yes - the number in the GetDecimal method is the index of **the column** you wish to read - since you only have a single column in your SQL statement, that column index has to be 0 all the time.